# How can I verify that sqlite file belongs to my android app before restoring from it

Tags: android, sqlite, backup

I have implemented simple backup/restore solution in my app a long time ago. The principle is simple when creating a backup an internal database is copied to external storage, when restoring from backup - external db-file is copied to internal database.

But the problem comes when I try to restore from backup file from another app (which obviously do not contains tables that my app needs). How could I verify that `somefile.db` or `somefile.sqlite` is actually a backup of my app? and it does contain needed schema. Because if I restore from random file.db, my app crashes with message that database does not contain needed table

```
fun restoreDbFromUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    try {
        val cr = context.contentResolver

        cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
            ?.use { pfd ->
                FileInputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                    .use { fis -> // TODO before coping, I need verify that this file is actually correct database, with all needed tables
                        dbOpenHelper.close()
                        internalDbFile.transferFrom(fis)                           

                        return true
                    }
            }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        presenter.toastPresenter.onShowErrorToast(e.localizedMessage)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    presenter.toastPresenter.onShowErrorToast()
    return false
}

val internalDbFile: File
    get() = context.getDatabasePath("prana_breath.sqlite")

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun File.transferFrom(srcInput: FileInputStream) {
    FileOutputStream(this).use { dstOut ->
        dstOut.channel.use { dstChannel ->
            srcInput.channel.use { srcChannel ->
                dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun FileChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel: FileChannel) {
    this.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size())
}
```

Comment: The [application_id](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_application_id) pragma is meant for just such a thing. Set it when creating a new database, check it when opening an existing one.

Comment: @Shawn Could you please show me some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first open the file and check the first 16 bytes of the header it must be **"SQLite format 3\000"**.

e.g. :-

```
const val SQLITEFILEHEADER = "SQLite format 3\u0000"
private fun isFileSQLiteDatabase(f: File): Boolean {
    val fis: InputStream
    if (!f.isFile) return false
    val header = ByteArray(16)
    try {
        fis = FileInputStream(f)
        fis.read(header)
        if (String(header) != SQLITEFILEHEADER) {
            fis.close()
            return false
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

That would elimiate virtually all non db files. To then check that the database has the expected tables (and/or other entities), you could then open the file as an SQLiteDatabase using one of the SQliteDatabase's [**openDatabase**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) methods and then query the **sqlite_master** table to check that the expected tables (and/or other entities) exist as expected, ensuring that you close the database.

So you could have something along the lines of :-

```
private fun isDBValid(f: File, entityList: Array<String>): Boolean {

    var matchcount = 0
    if (!isFileSQLiteDatabase(f)) return false
    try {
        val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(f.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
        val csr = db.query("sqlite_master", null, null, null, null, null, null)
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            for (s in entityList) {
                if (s.toLowerCase() == csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")).toLowerCase()) {
                    matchcount++
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        csr.close()
        db.close()
    } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
        return false;
    }
    return matchcount != entityList.size
}
```

- The String array passed would be the list of the tables (or other entities, indexes, views, triggers etc.) that must be found.

You could then use :-

```
fun restore DbFromUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    //<<<<<  DB VERIFICATION >>>>>
    if (isDBValid(File(uri.path), requiredEntities)) {
    } else {
        return false
    }
    try {
        val cr = context.contentResolver

        cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
            ?.use { pfd ->
                FileInputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                    .use { fis -> // TODO before coping, I need verify that this file is actually correct database, with all needed tables !!!!DONE ABOVE!!!!
                        dbOpenHelper.close()
                        internalDbFile.transferFrom(fis)                           

                        return true
                    }
            }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        presenter.toastPresenter.onShowErrorToast(e.localizedMessage)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    presenter.toastPresenter.onShowErrorToast()
    return false
}
```

- Note the above is in-principle code, and has not been tested or run and may therefore contain some errors.

Comment: Seem like a solution, will try it in practice and accept. Is it possible to SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase with uri which is returned by storage access browser? Because my app doesn't have read/write storage permission.

Comment: @OleksandrAlbul if you can't read it before the copy, then just do the checking after the copy passing internalDbFile, perhaps deleting the file if it's invalid before returning false.